# Write a recursive function called rev, which reverses the order of elements in an array

Tags: python

Im new in this coding platform.

So i have a work to do which is reversing the order of elementsin an array recursively.

So here is what i did:

```
A= [4,2,7,3,9,1]

def rev(A):
    if (len(A)==1):
        return A[0]
    else:
        return A[-1],pri(A[:-1])
print (rev(A))
```

> Output:
>
> (1, (4, (2, (7, (3, 9)))))

so i dont understand what i did wrongly,and if you can do it i want to do the output with ; instead of () things.
I have to do the program in python 3.0 or later versions.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `pri` function do?

Comment: before this code i write a recursivefunction with pri(A) thank you after i changed it to rev it works, but how do i replace the() with ; ?

Comment: I think `pri` is `rev` -> It is recursive

Comment: the best way to reverse an iterable is the alien smile `A[::-1]`, try it!

Comment: second, use `yield` instead of `return` in your function, and call recursively after yielding. I hope it makes you code works

Comment: i cant use any other functions like yield other than return , sorry about that:(

Comment: 1) Please edit your code to change `pri` to `rev` (or vice versa). In its current state your code is confusing. 2) I realise that you're trying to reverse a list recursively as a learning exercise, but _please_ don't do this in real code. There are a couple of efficient built-in ways to reverse lists (and other ordered containers) in Python. Also, recursion in Python isn't very efficient and it should only be used when it's appropriate to the problem domain, eg when processing recursive data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as below:

```
A= [4,2,7,3,9,1]

def rev(A):
    if len(A)==1:
        return A[0]
    lst = rev(A[:-1])
    return str(A[-1]) + ';' + str(lst)

print rev(A)
```

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1;9;3;7;2;4
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. 
The problem is that you return an `int` (in the first return statement) and a tuple (in the second return statement) instead of a list:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]

def rev(li):
    if len(li) == 1:
        return [li[0]]
    return [li[-1]] + rev(li[:-1])

print('; '.join(map(str, rev(li))))
```

**EDITED** to reflect wanted format of the output.

Comment: i did as you said but the output shouldn`t be like this [1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 4]  but like this 1; 9; 3; 7; 2; 4

Comment: @mamikun Ok, edited my answer. You should update your question

Comment: yes that was my fault:D its done as you said thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Function that does already exists in Python:

```
a = [4,2,7,3,9,1]

print a[::-1]
# [1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 4]

a.reverse()
print a
# [1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 4]
```

Comment: i cant use any other built in functions other than print and return but thank you:)

Comment: OP explicitly said they are required to achieve this in  a recursive manner.